# How should I further diagnose my FOLLOW-UP clothes dryer problem (no heat, stops mid-cycle)?

Tags: dryer, appliances

A few months ago, I asked [How should I further diagnose my clothes dryer problem (no heat, stops mid-cycle)?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/249647) and got some great feedback. The problem was quite obviously a failed heating coil which was easily replaced. The dryer ran well after that.

Until sometime this week. *This* time around, I have the same symptoms but when I disassembled the dryer, I can see that the heating coil is intact and a multimeter shows that is has very low (~10Ω) resistance when cold.

A quick recap:
[image]

> I believe the one with the white label (item #145160) is the "high-limit thermostat" part #33 offered [here](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/product/2eh0n2c7at-0026-417/id-3204267), since that's the one that's mounted directly to the heating element. (The drum is on the bottom of the image, the real panel of the unit is on the top of the image, and the heating element is behind the cosmetically-rusted protective shielding.) The other component appears to be the "thermal limiter" part #36 offered [here](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/product/16vx4aub1a-0026-417/id-134120900).
>
> Neither component shows any resistance across the terminals when connected (that is, my ohmmeter behaves the same whether I connect the probes to the terminals of those components or to each other: jumps up to ~20ohm, then drops to zero).

Any suggestions for how to proceed?

***UPDATE***

I removed the drum from the dryer and ran it on high heat just to see if the heating element comes on *and it does* after a minute or so.

I had some lint build-up in the ~8ft 2-90-degree-elbow run out to my outside vent which I have completely cleared. I will re-assemble and try again. It's possible the unit was stopping because it was actually upset and not because no heat was being applied.

Comment: So use logic and test all the other bits in the circuit.

Comment: @SolarMike The circuit looks like board -> wires -> those two components which seem to be fine -> coil -> more wires -> board. So.. not much more I can competently test myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's been a month and the dryer has been working fine.

I suspect the problem was just air-flow and now the high-heat sensor is just happy with a nice and clean vent.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a cool cycle and if it stops mid cycle it is probably the timer.  If that is the problem consider the price of replacement of either the timer or dryer. From looking at the photo I would guess you have had over 10 years good service from it.